# Reusable Database Class

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, class

I have the following code to query the database, get the data, set each property for the object, and then return that object. In this case, it is an impact object that has the properties `FinancialImpactId` and `EffectiveDate`.
Throughout my project I query the database several times like the example below using objects that have the associated property name in the database.

Is there a way to create a generic reusable class that would take in the following parameters: object to be returned or the type, the connection, and the query text?

It would then return the object and set each property like below but dynamically and would be reusable.

```
try
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = connection.ConnectionString;
        conn.Open();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = " SELECT TOP 1 fi.financialimpactid, 
                               fi.effectivedate " +
                              " FROM FinancialImpact fi " +
                              " INNER JOIN [Case] c ON c.caseid = 
                                fi.caseid " +
                              " WHERE fi.isDeleted = 0 AND 
                                c.IsDeleted = 0";

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();

                impact.FinancialImpactId = reader.GetInt32(0);
                impact.EffectiveDate = reader.GetDateTime(1);
            }


        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM e.g. Entity Framework? Don't re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: @DaleBurrell Not yet. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: A set of docs from Microsoft, highlighting various ways of doing the same thing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-simple-data-application-by-using-adonet?view=vs-2017

Comment: U can try linqtosql as light weight ORM

Comment: Linqtosql is defunct though

Comment: Also if you can't or don't want to use EF, there is also [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) "micro-ORM". I use it a lot for legacy/bad database architectures and it gets the job done nicely.

Comment: @derekmckinnon I may actually look into Dapper. I think it will be easier to implement instead of reworking everything to use EF. Is is possible to create a generic reusable class with it for db calls?

Comment: Yes, Dapper is super flexible. By default it will return `dynamic` objects that allow you to just access the db results by their name as set in the query. However, if you modify your SQL query and have the names reflect the properties in your strongly-typed models (ex `Impact.EffectiveDate`), then you can call dapper's generic method and supply `Impact` as the generic type and it maps the result set to the type

Comment: What I did with Dapper in the legacy system I mentioned was extracting the existing raw calls into repository classes (ex. UserRepository) where each method creates/gets a SqlConnection and uses Dapper to query strongly-typed models. If you want a more "Active Record" approach, you can embed dapper into the models themselves but I find that approach less desirable personally. It's hard to describe the entire architecture in a comment, but this is the basic gist. You have a lot of choice depending on your needs and constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ORM like [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/) is certainly the better option here, but you can absolutely create a class that could query the database this way.  You won't have parametrised queries or transactions, and you really won't save that much in re-usability, since every time you call it you'd need to provide lots of code to get it to function in the first place.

An example.  Take a query class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace QueryExample {
    public class Query {
        private readonly SqlConnection _connection;

        public Query(SqlConnection connection) {
            _connection = connection;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Run<T>(string text, Func<SqlDataReader, T> builder) {
            var results = new List<T>();

            try {
                _connection.Open();

                using (var command = new SqlCommand()) {
                    command.Connection = _connection;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = text;

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                        while (reader.Read())
                            results.Add(builder(reader));
                }

                _connection.Close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

...now take an example of running this class:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace QueryExample {
    public class Example {
        public static void Run() {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(string.Empty)) {
                var query = new Query(connection);
                const string text = "SELECT TOP 1 fi.financialimpactid, " +
                    "fi.effectivedate " +
                    " FROM FinancialImpact fi " +
                    " INNER JOIN [Case] c ON c.caseid = " +
                    "fi.caseid " +
                    " WHERE fi.isDeleted = 0 AND " +
                    "c.IsDeleted = 0";
                var results = query.Run(text, GetData);
                // do something with the results
            }
        }

        private static Data GetData(SqlDataReader reader) => new Data {
            FinancialImpactId = reader.GetInt32(0),
            EffectiveDate = reader.GetDateTime(1)
        };
    }

    internal class Data {
        public int FinancialImpactId { get; set; }
        public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You see how running the class doesn't give you that much usability, especially since you will always have to return a result (making `INSERT INTO`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` "result builders" more difficult to define), and it always has to be a list (not as big of a problem, but always having to do an empty check and accessing the first record can get old fast)?

This is one reason why you'd use an ORM nowadays.  They not only simplify query creation, but also make parametrisation unnecessary.